# JasperReport with multiple pages on a single file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'd like to know if it's possible to fill a report template several times and them export the results to a single PDF file. As of now, this is my code to generate a single report:

```
            String input=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/report.jrxml");

        File reporte= new File(input);

        design = JRXmlLoader.load(reporte);

        report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
        print= JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, new JREmptyDataSource());

        byte[]archivo=JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
        InputStream stream=new ByteArrayInputStream(archivo);
```

The report template would be the same for all the pages but one parameter would be different per each generated report.